# How do i deploy UAT and Development SharePoint solution on the same server?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 Server and i have following items in my SharePoint solution

- Couple of web parts
- State Machine Work flow (which will be integrated to an Infopath form library)
- Infopath task edit forms

Lets say this solutions is deployed to http://[SharePoint201Server]:[PortNumber-**x**]/

This is the only server i have (No extra server for UAT), and what ever has been done so far needs to be given for user acceptance testing (UAT). I may create one more site at http://[SharePoint201Server]:[PortNumber-**y**]/ for it.

My problme is that how do i maintain two copies of my source code ? I will have to continue development on the same set of source code for next UAT release. I simply can not create simple copies of the source code as it will have same Assembly name and feature id, etc..As if i do so, any changes on under Development source code would affect UAT assemblies.

One thing i can do is to create seperate projects for UAT and Development with different Features and Assembly names, but is not that too much of an unneccesory work ?

What can be the best approach in such situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest use sand boxed solution and create two site collection one for UAT and other for production. deploy your solutions individually on each sandbox solution. Sandbox solutions are deployed in bin not in GAC so you would not be having trouble code duplication

Comment: Ashutosh, you must be aware that Sanbox solution limits the types of SharePoint project items that you can deploy to the SharePoint server and also some SharePoint APIs cannot be used in Sandboxed solutions. When i set SandBox solution to true, and tried to deploy i got lot of compilation errors specifically related to Project item compatibiliy with SandBox solution. E.g. I have a sharepoint mapped folder 'ISAPI' which contains my .asmx file, which obviously sandbox solution is not able to deploy :(

Comment: missed that you are using state machine workflow as well. only solution is to maintain two copies of code or create two environments

Comment: Solution does not have to be sandboxed to be deployed to the web application bin directory, so this idea might still work....

Answer (score 2):

There is no best approach for this. You need to have different environments for development and UAT.

If the availability of machine is limitation, One possible solution is to have VM environment of the same machine for development and actual environment for UAT.

That obviously requires sophisticated hardware configuration to run both simultaneously.